# On which intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ is the system $(t, ..., t^k)$ linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Are there any real intervals on which the system $(t, ..., t^k)$ is linearly dependent?

I think $(t, ..., t^k)$ is linearly independent on all of $\mathbb{R}$, since we have for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, for $a_i \in \mathbb{R}, i \in \{1,...,k\}: \sum_{i=1}^k a_i t^i
= 0 $, taking k derivatives with respect to t yields $k(k-1)...1 a_k = 0$, therefore $a_k = 0$ and then using the i-th equation obtained from taking the i-th derivative given the coefficients for $a_{i+1}, ..., a_k$ given $a_i=0 \forall i \in {1, ..., k}$. Is there something wrong in this argumentation?

Comment: Is $t$ a function of x? Or is it a polynomial? The notation of $t^i(x)$ is confusing.

Comment: You are right, that was a mistake, t is the independent variable and not a function,I fixed that.

Comment: The question is phrased a bit oddly. What does it mean for a system to be dependent on an interval? If it means values of t, 0 and 1 are bad. If it means coefficients $a_i$, I see no problem with your argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of functions $\{1, t, ..., t^k\}$ is always linearly indendent when the domain is any subset of $\Bbb C$ having $k + 1$ or more points. Your argument is one proof when the domain includes an interval.

It can also be proven without calculus by noting that a non-zero polynomial of degree $\le k$ can only have at most $k$ roots, so the only way for $\sum_{i=0}^k a_i t^i
= 0$ for at least $k + 1$ values of $t$ would be for it to be the zero polynomial. I.e., for $a_i = 0$ for all $i$.